# How to make child img respect parent when it has items above

Tags: html, css

I'm not able to make the img respect the parent's container when it has more items above it.

Html

```
<div class="box">
  <h4>Some random text that will overflow the image</h4>
  <div class="box2">
    <img class="img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Yd98vOJTL._AC_SY679_.jpg" alt="Poster not available"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
      border: 1px solid;
      border-radius: 3px;
      margin: .3rem;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2rem 0;
      height: 300px;
}

.box2 {
  border: 1px solid;
      border-radius: 3px;
      text-align: center;
      height: 100%;
      border-color: red;
      display: inline-block;
      box-sizing: content-box;
}

.img {
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

h4{
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dsxhy57k/1/

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is to use the [CSS Flexible Box Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) combined with `overflow: hidden`

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  }
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column; 
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: .3rem; 
  height: 300px;
}
  
.box2 {
  flex: 2 ; 
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;   
  padding: 1rem;
  
}
.box2 img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h4>Some random text that will overflow the image</h4>

  <div class="box2">
   <img class="img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Yd98vOJTL._AC_SY679_.jpg" alt="Poster not available"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

An other would be using the [calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) to set the height of your element `.box2`

```css
.box {
      border: 1px solid;
      border-radius: 3px;
      margin: .3rem;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2rem 0;
      height: 300px;
}

.box2 {
  border: 1px solid;
      border-radius: 3px;
      text-align: center;
      /*height: 100%;*/
      height: calc(100% - 32px);/*here 32px is the space reserved for the h4, this cold well be the height of the h4*/
      border-color: red;
      display: inline-block;
      box-sizing: content-box;
}

.img {
    height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

h4{
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h4>Some random text that will overflow the image</h4>
  <div class="box2">
    <img class="img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Yd98vOJTL._AC_SY679_.jpg" alt="Poster not available"/>
  </div>
</div>
```